# Replica table partition in EDB PostgreSQL

Tags: database, database-replication, postgresql-15, edb, guid-partition-table

I have problem when I replica my table with replication console from EDB Postgres.
the trouble is the table have different number row from primary to replica when I partition the table. but when the table not partition the number row same from primary and replica.

any suggestion?

Thank you before

I try to re replicate but still same.

my expect is when I partition the table number row is same from primary to replica.